# Setting up a session in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, session

I want to transfer an object from one page to another. It's a search results page when clicking on a result it leads to a page needed. So I need to transfer the object which has data of the required result.

I tried using services and factory but the data gets reset whenever I loaded the next page
Also I would need to store client details for other pages too, So I think sessions are a better choice

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible without server intervention. If you want to share the data on client itself, you need to use Local or Session Storage, which store the information as key-value pairs.

To set an item in the local storage

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

To get an item from the local storage

```
window.localStorage.getItem("key"); // returns "value"
```

Local storage is persisted until the browser/you manually clean it. On the other hand, session storage is cleared as soon as the tab/window is closed.

[More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: yes, I need the data storage just for the client side I will go through the link thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways, here is one among them. You can use localStorage if you want to trade minor objects or variables across the application.

You can set the object in a localStorage as below

```
localStorage.setItem('objectNameAsKey', realObjectReference);
```

You can also stringify the JSON object if needed.

```
 localStorage.setItem('objectNameAsKey', JSON.stringify(realObjectReference));
```

Wherever you need this object, you can get it using the key

```
localStorage.getItem('objectNameAsKey');
```

When you fetch the stringify'd object, you can do as below,

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('objectNameAsKey'));
```